# Splitting a single payment to multiple accounts

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing, razorpay, balanced-payments

Me and my friends had an idea to make an payment app that can split the payments and send it to the receiver and a NGO at the same time. If the requested amount is $17.57(hypothetically) and the user pays 20$,then the remaining 2.43$ should be going to the NGOs with the user's permission. How to split that payment amount? I'm totally new to this . SO,Is it possible to make something out of this? If Yes , How? Thank You In Advance.

Comment: What's an NGO? Regardless, it sounds like you're looking for a payment gateway recommendation that supports this. While Stack Overflow isn't appropriate for these types of questions, the Googlable buzzword you're looking for is `Marketplace payments`

Comment: It depends upon which payment you used for your application. RazorPay payment gateway distribute payment in multiple accounts.